# Material UI Stepper - How to align stepper icons and labels to left

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to align stepper icons and labels to left. I was able to align labels but not icons.

I was trying align-items: start but then the lines didn't match up with icons.

Any help would be great, thanks.

[image]

```
export const StyledStepper = styled(Stepper)(({ theme }) => ({
    [`&.${stepConnectorClasses.active}`]: {
        [`& .${stepConnectorClasses.line}`]: {
            borderColor: '#ff0000',
        },
    }
}));

export const StyledStepperIconRoot = styled('div')<{
    ownerState: { active?: boolean };
}>(({ theme, ownerState }) => ({
    color: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? theme.palette.grey[700] : '#eaeaf0',
    display: 'flex',
    height: 22,
    alignItems: 'center',
    ...(ownerState.active && {
        color: '#784af4',
    }),
    '& .customStepIcon-completedIcon': {
        color: '#3DA683',
        zIndex: 1,
    },
}));

export const StyledStepLabel = styled(StepLabel)({
    '& .MuiStepLabel-label': {
        textAlign: 'left !important',
    },
    '& .MuiStepLabel-iconContainer': {
        justifyContent: 'flex-start !important',
        marginRight: '8px',
    },
});

export const StyledStep = styled(Step)({
    '& .MuiStep-root': {
        justifyContent: 'flex-start !important',
    },
});

export const StyledStepperConnector = styled(StepConnector)(({ theme }) => ({
    [`&.${stepConnectorClasses.active}`]: {
        [`& .${stepConnectorClasses.line}`]: {
            borderColor: '#3DA683',
        },
    },
}));
```